# How to highlight day on Bootstrap Datepicker that is two days in the future?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a requirement for a form that uses a bootstrap datepicker that the earliest day that can be selected is two days in the future from today's date, AND that on the calendar the date that is highlighted to start with is two days from today's date.

With the following code, I can set the startDate as two days in the future, but I can't seem to highlight that day in the future when the datepicker first fires.

Appreciate any suggestions...

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()+2);

           $('#dpExpectedStartDate').datepicker({
            weekStart: 0,
            daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: date,
        });
</script>
```

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration: startDate:'2d'

Comment: @Vickel  Yes, that is another way to set the startDate as two days in the future.  The problem I'm stumbling on is highlighting that date that is two days in the future.   This will be a visual clue for the user to see that they can't pick today or tomorrow, but must pick two days in the future.

Comment: sorry, I didn't read carefully enough through your question and missed the part you are actually asking. Try to find out which class is used to define the startdate and change its css accordingly with $('.startdateclass').css()